# Is there any canon reference to a spell that tells time?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

In Harry Potter fanfic, it is relatively established fanon that timekeeping is done using the *Tempus* charm, which displays the current time in the air.

As answered in [How do people at Hogwarts usually tell the time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/98746/how-do-people-at-hogwarts-usually-tell-the-time), this charm is never mentioned in the books -- instead, normal clocks and watches are used. That doesn't mean it's impossible for magic to tell time, however, just that it's not in general use.

In the somewhat-expanded canon that includes the books, the movies, Pottermore, and "authoritative" tweets by Rowling, is there any reference to any *spell* used for timekeeping?

Comment: I wonder if a magical time spell would adjust for time zone, daylight savings, leap years. leap seconds etc...?

Comment: In the films Moody told Harry that at Harry's age Cedric could enchant a clock __to tell time__. Make of it what you want.

Comment: You mean, a spell other than *accio clock*?

Comment: It probably depends on whether anyone finds value in knowing the precise time. If there is a clock tower, and some kind of chime, that's probably good enough to get to classes at school. The more precisely you know what the time is, and how often you can know it, binds you more firmly to those who would consume your time. Not having a clock, or a watch, is liberating after having others divide up your time, by the minute, for years. So the real question is: do wizards/witches need to know, or care, what time it is?

Answer (score 7):

### Spell that tells the time?

Nope.

### Magical timepieces

Why, certainly.

> *The clock on the wall opposite him had only one hand and no numbers at
> all. Written around the edge were things like ‘Time to make tea’,
> ‘Time to feed the chickens’ and ‘You’re late’.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</sup></sub>

Comment: Not to mention the watches young witches and wizards receive when they come of age

Comment: @albusseveruspotter - Are they magical though?

Comment: Dumbledore also had a clock on his wall, if I recall correctly.

Comment: This answer would be stronger with some mention of what references you checked and how -- I'm not expecting an exhaustive analysis, but something more than one word, maybe?

Comment: @LucasY. - I checked every reference.

Comment: @Valorum well, they're described as randomly moving, levitating planets, so I'd say they're magical. plus, Hermione says in GoF that muggle machines don't work at Hogwarts/MoM, so they'd have to be magic, wouldn't they?

Comment: @albusseveruspotter - Muggle *machines* work just fine (all three of the gang [wear wrist-watches](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/98748/20774)). Electricity doesn't