# Why do wizards in Harry Potter receive a watch when they turn 17?

Tags: harry-potter

I think it's like being allowed to drink. But in Harry's 3rd year they start drinking butterbeer, so maybe it is a right?

Comment: For the same reason as [traditional wedding anniversary gifts](https://apracticalwedding.com/traditional-modern-anniversary-gift-ideas/): because it's a tradition.  It has nothing to do with "being allowed" anything, it isn't as if younger wizards aren't allowed to wear watches!

Comment: Similar to Pen & Pencil sets on graduation, it's a tradition.  There is probably a root cause behind it, but it may well have been long since forgotten.  With adulthood tends to come adult responsibilities, and the care-free, non-time-bound (mostly) days of childhood gone, I suppose it's a sensible gift...

Comment: @K-H-W: I think it's worth pointing out as an out-of-universe fact whether it is a tradition in the wizarding world, or a real UK tradition that JKR took over for the wizards (and that may be entirely unknown to readers, and visitors on this site). (Speaking of which, is that "Pen & Pencil sets on graduation" something from HP, or a real tradition somewhere?)

Comment: I think it's because they don't wear cellphones.

Comment: Because time keeps on slipping into the future.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Pen & Pencil sets are a RL tradition; I've both received and given them a few times.  There are others that are profession specific; off the top of my head, a nice briefcase / brief-bag / etc., is common for Lawyers when they graduate (or pass the bar, some places), and I know passing along an old, high-end medical tool (thermometer, stethoscope, etc.) is common in the medical field (not to use, necessarily, but as a keepsake/recognition type thing) - These at least show relevance to what is being celebrated, but other traditions may have, but now have forgotten origins.

Comment: @Sulthan Wait. Does anyone 'wear' a mobile phone ?

Answer (score 25):

## It's simply a traditional 17th birthday gift in the wizarding world.

Giving a wizard a watch on their seventeenth birthday is a tradition in the wizarding world. Exactly how this tradition started is unclear, but, like blowing out the candles on a birthday cake, it's become a tradition that people probably follow without necessarily knowing its origins.

> “Inside was a watch very like the one Mr and Mrs Weasley had given Ron for his seventeenth; it was gold, with stars circling round the face instead of hands.
>
> ‘It’s traditional to give a wizard a watch when he comes of age,’ said Mrs Weasley, watching him anxiously from beside the cooker.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 7 (The Will of Albus Dumbledore)*</sup></sub>

## Younger wizards are most likely allowed to wear watches.

Harry sees a shine from one of the Weasley twins' watches, and this would have been long before they turned seventeen.

> “Once he caught sight of a flash of gold but it was just a reflection from one of the Weasleys’ wristwatches, and once a Bludger decided to come pelting his way, more like a cannon ball than anything, but Harry dodged it and Fred Weasley came chasing after it.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 11 (Quidditch)*</sup></sub>

There's also a mention of multiple people checking their watches while waiting for the Triwizard Tournament champions to be announced.

> “Everyone watched, waiting … a few people kept checking their watches …
>
> ‘Any second,’ Lee Jordan whispered, two seats away from Harry.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 16 (The Goblet of Fire)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Ironically, it's not really _that much_ of a tradition since wristwatches were not available at all before ca. 1880-1890 and only became widely used after 1917. Hardly something a more than thousand years old wizarding society would consider a "traditional" timespan. But alas, it's exactly what is written in the books, so you're of course right.

Comment: @Damon Traditional to give *a watch* prior to wrist watches it was likely a pocket watch.

Comment: @Skooba That's a really good point. I have several of those though it's because I collect them; it first started after my grandmother gave me one decades ago. Yes pocket watches would suffice instead.

Answer (score 13):

Mrs Weasley explains this in *Deathly Hallows*:

> Harry sat down, took the square parcel she had indicated and unwrapped it.  Inside was a watch very like the one Mr and Mrs Weasley had given Ron for his seventeenth; it was gold, with stars circling around the face instead of hands.
>
> 'It's traditional to give a wizard a watch when he comes of age,' said Mrs Weasley, watching him anxiously from beside the cooker.

There's nothing more to it: traditions don't need reasons.

[This answer of Valorum's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/98748/5930) establishes that young wizards are permitted to wear watches.